# Improving short text cluster performance

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am currently doing short text clustering and have implemented gsdmm from this [github link](https://github.com/rwalk/gsdmm) with a dataset of size 2675 and vocab size of 1231.

However, the clustering result is not very accurate and I think this might be because the dataset contains similar words/ phrases that have different meanings in the domain that I'm working on.

Examples of similar phrases that has different meanings:

```
"business process management", "business process modelling" and "business model canvas"
"process workflow model", "process orientation" and "process innovation"
```

I have tried using bigrams and trigrams but it didn't solve the problem.

Are there any other ways which I can improve the results? Are there any other algorithms that are good for clustering short text?

Answer (score 0):

Did you play with the parameters of the GSDMM Algorithm? My results changed dramatically when I used the algorithm with diffrent alpha and beta values. So if you have an idea how many cluster you expect, you can look for an alpha beta combination that is in the right area.
If you don´t have that information, I would suggests you to try diffrent values and compare the results.

Other than GSDMM I don´t know any short text clustering algorithms.